# Google admob Download Tracking help?

Tags: android, admob

Is it possible to add the google admob download tracking in your android application without actually making an 'ad'. I have to add this but not to track all the events, i have to do this only for getting the number of times the app has been downloaded by the user.
I have consulted the link

http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android_App_Download_Tracking

but it says u have to make a custom ad to do so. which is not required in my case. Please can someone elaborate the steps that i need to take to implement admob download tracking. or provide a sample code that can help me out. Let me remind you that i have to do this tracking just  for getting the number of times the app has been downloaded by a user from the market. and also if there is a way to test this as app is still not live. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

App conversion tracking for Android is not currently publicly available.  It is only available for "managed accounts" according to the doc.  It is currently undergoing development and testing, so look for it's public release sometime soon.